# Java - Abstract factory using factory method vs prototype

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract, abstraction

Can someone explain differences between Factory Method and Prototype in Abstract Factory? And if someone could provide examples of both approaches, would be great. I looked for examples myself, but only found Abstract factory examples without saying what approach was used or explained those approaches.

Comment: See: http://www.oodesign.com/prototype-pattern.html, http://www.oodesign.com/abstract-factory-pattern.html and http://www.oodesign.com/factory-method-pattern.html

Comment: Maybe there are examples were both approaches are used at the same time? When abstract factory is combined with factory method and the other aproach, when abstract factory is combined with prototype?